# Frequency or Wavenlenght; which changes when light is passing from rarer to denser medium?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, visible-light

what changes; Frequency or Wavelength when light passes from a rarer to a denser medium?And Why?

Comment: See http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/226842/24774

Comment: @fffred The answer you linked doesn't explain *why* the frequency remains constant. I think that should be explained.

Comment: Well, this one gives an answer even if it is not very detailed http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/21338/24774

Comment: Frequency is controlled by the source of the light, not the medium that the light is passing through.

Comment: Which one allows the boundary conditions to be maintained at the interface?